# show mrss content with all types of media provided by mrss as wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to show mrss feeds served by http://allhiphop.com/feed/ as wordpress posts in a custom page template. The title and a brief description appear for each feed but I'm unable to show any images, videos etc.. in the page. Below is the code that I'm using.

```
<?php
include_once(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/rss.php');
$feed = fetch_rss('http://allhiphop.com/feed');
$items = array_slice($feed->items, 0, 10);
?>

<?php if (!empty($items)) : ?>
<?php foreach ($items as $item) : ?>

<h2><a href="<?php echo $item['link']; ?>">
<?php echo $item['title']; ?></a></h2>

<p><?php echo $item['description']; ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm not sure whether I should use fetch_rss or fetch_feed. I know I'm not doing this right. If someone can guide me in the right direction, that would be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is very old, but anyway if it helps somebody.

The way I did is put the image in description. That is, in the description I have a `<img>` tag which links to the image. See http://www.applegrew.com/util/if.xml for example.